# Is it possible to implement a function interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I would like to be able to do this

```
class MyFunc extends ((s: string) => boolean) { ... }
```

so that an instance of `MyFunc` can be used as a function which takes a string as input and returns a boolean as follows:

```
const f = new MyFunc();
const b: boolean = f('someString');
```

Is this possible in TypeScript?

In languages such as Scala, one can extend the type `String => Boolean`, and provide an `apply` method to achieve this.

```
class MyFunc extends (String => Boolean)
val f = new MyFunc()
val b: Boolean = f("someString")
```

Answer (score 43):

Perhaps you are thinking of something like this?

```
interface FunctionInterface {
    (s: string): boolean;
}

const f: FunctionInterface = s => true;
const b: boolean = f('someString');
```

Comment: Here is the detail doc for function types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: Is this possible with non-arrow functions? Something like `function myFunc(s) implements FunctionInterface { return true; }`

Comment: @KasparPoland You can do `const myFunc: FunctionInterface = function myFunc...`, but that's pretty roundabout. You cannot type a whole function declaration, only a variable.

Answer (score 16):

There is no default `apply` concept in TypeScript, but there are ways of creating typed objects that are also functions.

```
interface MyCallable {
    (param1: string, param2: number): string;

    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
    extraMethod: (param1: boolean) => boolean;
}

function makeMyCallable(prop1: string, prop2: number): MyCallable {
    let that = ((param1: string, param2: number) => param1 + param2) as MyCallable;

    that.prop1 = prop1;
    that.prop2 = prop2;
    that.extraMethod = (param1: boolean) => !param1;

    return that;
}

let mc = makeMyCallable("3", 4);

mc("3", 4);
mc.prop1 = "string";
mc.prop2 = 5;
mc.extraMethod(false);
```

Comment: @SalientBrain I've updated the answer to work in TS3.2.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a simple function to accept a string and return a boolean, you don't need to use a class for this.

```
const myFunc = (s: string): boolean => {
  return s !== "";  //whatever logic is needed here
};
```

But, yes you can extend classes in TypeScript

```
class MyBaseClass {
  constructor() { }

  public doThing = (s: string): boolean => {
    return s !== "";  //whatever logic is needed here
  }
}

class MyFunc extends MyBaseClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

const f = new MyFunc();
const b = f.doThing("hi"); //returns a boolean
```

---

#### Updated for response to comment

As mentioned below in another answer, you cannot really `new` up a class, assign that instance to a variable and then call it as a function.  You could do that on the creation though, like this:

```
class MyBaseClass {
  constructor() { }

  public doThing = (s: string): boolean => {
    return s !== "";  //whatever logic is needed here
  }
}

class MyFunc extends MyBaseClass {
  constructor(private s: string) {
    super();
    this.doThing(this.s);
  }
}

const f = new MyFunc("hi"); //returns a boolean
```

You can play with the above code [on the Typescript playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20MyBaseClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20public%20doThing%20%3D%20(s%3A%20string)%3A%20boolean%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20s%20!%3D%3D%20%22%22%3B%20%20%2F%2Fwhatever%20logic%20is%20needed%20here%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyFunc%20extends%20MyBaseClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(private%20s%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.doThing(this.s)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20f%20%3D%20new%20MyFunc(%22hi%22)%3B%20%2F%2Freturns%20a%20boolean)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But you'd have to write `f.doThing('str')` to use `f` as a function, right? The point of extending that function class is for `f` to be used as a function directly (i.e., called like this: `f('str')`)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on use case. Here several ways.  [https://typescriptlang.org/play/...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7.5#code/PTAEBEFMGMBsEMBOkAmoAWlmgPaNAJYC2ADngC6oBQ5AniZKAGYCCiA5gM6gC8oA2gDsArkQBGWADShO5RAUHsAujXqMmAJUjleoMThyxI8QaobMAkoMqIm8aIz4AKAHRuSSeEU4AuZmy4ASl4APmYtcioqEFAAWRNheFhYWiomYUFocgIcQUJOAFEAR0TYAAYnAA8-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-wIMQjD0bR8UgbZ2UwRkuQYTgXCiIgcBQYQjBcEi8LI0AlLwnjxyoCKdBQSA7FCnQYu40cxwSziKEeIZaNKMoGN3WB6MooMWJA9sgA)

*Somehow we imported*

- *as interface* @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/42841742/9412937
- *as function type*

```js
type fInterface = (...params: fArgs) => fRet
```

- *as separate types*

```js
type fArgs = [number, string]
type fRet = boolean
```

*No matter - they are interchangeable with [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterst) and [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet)*

*And we have function implemented wrong*

```js
function nop() {}
```

1. Manually  pick parameters type

```js
function isEqual0(x: fArgs[0], y: fArgs[1]): fRet {
  //return x == y //TS-ERROR: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'number' and 'string' have no overlap.ts(2367)
  return `${x}` == y
}
```

2. With [destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
function isEqual1(...args: fArgs): fRet {
  const [x, y] = args
  return `${x}` == y
}
```

3. With [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads). Strict usage but during implementation all parameters are `any`.

```js
function isEqual2(...args: Parameters<fInterface>): ReturnType<fInterface>
function isEqual2(x: any, y: any) {
  return x == y
}
```

4. After all we can validate by re-typing (like [typing-the-function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#typing-the-function)). Also there will be type validation in parent module in any case.

```js
function isEqual3(x: any, y: any) {
  const valid: typeof  isEqual3 extends fInterface ? true : never = true
  if (!valid)
    throw Error()
  return x == y
}

const _exports = {
  isEqual0, isEqual1, isEqual2, isEqual3, nop
}
, _exportCheck = _exports as  Record<keyof typeof _exports, fInterface> //TS-ERROR The types returned by 'nop(...)' are incompatible between these types.

module.exports = _exportCheck
export default _exportCheck
export {
  isEqual0, isEqual1, isEqual2, nop
}
```

So many ways to achieve TS-Error if something was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

If you only have this function in your interface, you can define it like

```
type FuncType = (s: string) => boolean;
```

to use it like

```
const myFunc: FuncType;
function getFunction(): FuncType {}
```

Comment: Your second example of use is incorrect. You would be creating a function called getFunction that returns a function of FuncType, not a boolean.

Comment: That second example is returning a function returning a boolean, which would look funny if defined directly.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said... And it's not what the author wanted. The author wanted to define a type for a function that takes a string and returns a boolean. What you're doing on the second line is you're defining a function that returns a function. And that is confusing. A `function` cannot implement an interface, at least not in the current TypeScript version. By looking at the second line, someone might think it's possible.